# Hiding bootstrap element when displaying on screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a project with a heavy printing component I am making use of the boostrap class `hidden-print` to hide elements that should appear on the screen, but not on the printed page.  This works perfectly.

I have one div, however, that should appear *only* on the printed page and never on any screen device.  My reading from `http://getbootstrap.com/css/` (in the section Print Classes) is that using the class `visible-print-block` should accomplish this.  Nevertheless, when I use this markup:

```
  <div class="visible-print-block">
  <img class="img-responsive center-block" src=". . ."/>
  </div>
```

my image is visible on both the screen and print versions.

How can I cause this div to be visible *only* on the printed page?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6BvB1tcKc8xsnm8uJIUs?p=preview that works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which minor version of Bootstrap 3 do you use? In 3.0 there is no class for visible-print-block. Make sure you use the latest bootstrap.

Or try to use:

```
.visible-print-block{display:none!important;}
```

And do not forget to make your element visible on media print:

```
@media print{ .visible-print-block{display:none!important;}}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Apparently this project is still at 3.0.1.  I will update.